# How to check the type of file while getting data from API whether the file is pdf or image so that it can be viewed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs, konvajs-reactjs

How to check the type of file while getting data from API whether the file is pdf or image so that it can be viewed?

How to check the type of file while getting data from API whether the file is pdf or image so that it can be viewed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share your snippet to narrow your question.